# pass an argument to jbehave execution

Tags: maven, argument-passing, jbehave

I want to pass some argument to jbehave test as a precondition to it's execution

for example

```
mvn clean install myArgument
```

is it something I can do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
                <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-stories</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <storyTimeoutInSecs>600</storyTimeoutInSecs>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>fileName</name>
                                    <value>${fileName}}</value>
                                </property>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/${fileName}</include>
                            </includes>
                            <scope>test</scope>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and maven command :

```
mvn clean install -DfileName="argument"
```